# Limit of Quotient of sums

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm looking for a reference giving insight into the following problem: Given $\frac{b_l^{(N)}}{c_l^{(N)}} \xrightarrow{N\to\infty} 0$ for every $l\in \mathbb N$. When does

$$\frac{\sum_{l=1}^N b_l^{(N)}}{\sum_{l=1}^N c_l^{(N)}}\xrightarrow{N\to\infty} 0?$$

Comment: haha. When the bottom series diverges and the top series converges the fraction centainly goes to zero

Comment: I'm more interested in the nontrivial cases, i.e. both numerator and denominator are divergent.